# How do I use storage with my containers in rancher on DigitalOcean and vSphere?

Tags: digital-ocean, vsphere, rancher

I'm am trying with both vSphere, and Digital Ocean and I am using the rancher interface to "Add Host".

I believe I have declared the volumes in the docker-compose.yml correctly.
(I have storage working just docker).

However I get this error.

> Error looking up volume plugin rancher-nfs: legacy plugin: plugin not
>   found

Looking into this, it seems that only RancherOS supports rancher-nfs, and not boot2docker.

How can I move forward?

Answer (score 0):

First you should ensure there is rancher-nfs.sock in /run/docker/plugins.
if not, you should make it by follows:

```
# ln -s /var/run/rancher/storage/rancher-nfs.sock rancher-nfs.sock
```